# Cannot Integrate Opencv With Qt

Tags: qt, opencv

I would like to integrate opencv249 with Qt 5.5. My .pro file is like that:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV249/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV249/opencv/build/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV249/opencv/build/include/opencv2

LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV249/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib

LIBS += -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249 -lopencv_features2d249 -lopencv_calib3d249
```

My code is like that:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Mat im=imread("1.jpg");
    imshow("kubi",im);  

    return a.exec();
}
```

It gives those errors:

```
    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QEAA@XZ)

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QEAA@AEBVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function main

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ)

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function main

    main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function main

    debug\Sercan.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: which compiler does your QtCreator use?

Comment: All of the C++ code that you use: Qt, OpenCV, and your project, must be compiled using the same version of Visual Studio. As long as that is the case, note the typo in your project file (see the answers) and you're otherwise set.

Comment: @KubaOber My kit name is Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC 2013 64 bit and it uses compiler Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (amd64). Besides, there is no option for Qt 5.5.0 MSVC 2012 64 bit.

Comment: @srcn The pre-built Qt images are there for your convenience. **Nothing will work until the compilers match**. If you use a compiler that no binary Qt build is available for, it is your job to build it yourself. Same goes for OpenCV. It'd be best if you forgot about the existence of any binary builds. Build it from the source and it will all work, and you'll have way more control over exactly what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Is your lib path correct?

Should you change

```
LIBS += -LC:/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib
```

with

```
LIBS += -LC:/OpenCV249/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib
```

?

It's only a wild guess, everything else looks OK...

Comment: Ok, can you update your question with the result of the following commands: `dir C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib` and `dir C:\OpenCV249\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib`?